# How to refetch data after create using Prisma in NextJS?

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo-client, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm loading data at build time using `getStaticProps`.

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany()
  return {
    props: { users }
  }
}
```

I have a form that creates new data:

```
const handleSubmit = async ({ name, score }) => {
  const body = { name, email }
  await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/users/post`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }
}
```

After submitting a form, I would like to refetch the users to display the new one in real time without reloading the page.

In `Apollo Client` there's a function called `refetchQueries` that is here to easily do just that, i.e. re-run the `graphQL` query whenever the mutation happened.  Is there a way to do a similar thing here, using plain NextJs+Prisma without graphQL?

Comment: Maybe you should move the user data fetching to the client-side entirely, rather than loading it at build time in `getStaticProps`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/next.js/incremental-static-regeneration) (ISR)

```js
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany()
  return {
    props: { users },
    revalidate: 60,
  }
}
```

You can define a `revalidation` time per-page (e.g. 60 seconds).
The initial request will show the cached page, and when the data gets updated, Next.js will trigger a rebuild with the updated data.

Comment: Is there a solution for app router?